# How to hide the table until a string is searched?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently interning as part of my school course at a small tech company and one of the projects I'm working on right now is making a web application with **`MVC`**.

The manager gave me a SQL database to work with and I've been following this tutorial by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to help me build the web app.

Now, the specific thing the manager wants me to do is hiding the table when someone loads the page and when a string is submitted into the search bar, the relevant information in the table matching the string shows up.

I've been looking everywhere, including SO how to do this for a few days now, no matter what code I try it doesn't seem to work! I've been trying different things using `HTML` and `JS`, following some examples posted here, I just can't figure out how to do it, the table flashes for a second when I click the search button, I think it's the page refreshing but why?

Here's my controller with the searchBar

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty    (searchString) ? "name_prmrnm" : "";
    var person = from p in db.persons
                 select p;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        person = person.Where(s => s.name.Contains(searchString));     
    }

    return View(person.ToList());
}
```

Here's my javascript in the View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function escondeTable(){
        var hideTab = document.getElementById("table-class");
        if (hideTab.style.display == 'none') {
            hideTab.style.display = '';
        }
    else {
            hideTab.style.display == 'none'
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here's my form:

```
<form action="/people/Index" method="post" onsubmit="escondeTable()">
        <p class="barraProc">
            @Html.TextBox("searchString", "", new { placeholder = "Insira um nome..." })
            <input type="button" value="Procurar">
        </p>
    </form>
```

Can anyone tell me what I could be using or doing?

Comment: You're submitting the form when you click the button (change the button from type="submit" to type="button")   If you do want to submit the form and update the page then you're going to need to use Ajax, rather than a postback.

Comment: @Archer Thank you, that's good to know! Is Ajax necessary for a web application in MVC? I mean aside from this problem I'm having.
Fixed up my code a little.

Comment: I'm not an MVC developer so can't say if there's a better approach than Ajax, but the submit button will definitely cause the page reload, so you'd lose the style change you made.

Comment: Changing it to <button> and <onclick> just displays my table and searching doesn't work... but looking at it when it's running in the browser points me to the <onclick> string, I'm not sure why? My code seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Ajax call. And one option then is this

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
 var hideTab = document.getElementById("table-class");
 hideTab.hide();
 });

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
var hideTab = document.getElementById("table-class");
hideTab.show();
 });
```

Comment: I can't get this to work either ):
Thank you for the help Jordi!

Comment: you have to call with ajax , search information about $.ajax or $.post, and later you can use  both functions i have writted you like a solution of: hidden a table while searching.. (you need ajax no form submitted)

Comment: Jordi, I just wanted to say thank you again, your answer (and Babevski's) put me on the right track to figuring out my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a proper approach?

I'd stay away from forms, because they cause a lot of headaches. Just use regular inputs and event listeners.

Also, I'd use a RESTful API, i.e. avoiding a POST method, and using a GET method to get the table data from the backend.

The API should serve the data on this URL `localhost/search/critieria`, where the user supplies the criteria.

You can render the table in the following way:

```
fetch("http://localhost/search/" + criteria)
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
    generateTable(data);
})
.catch((err) => err);
```

Here is a quick demo I made: https://jsfiddle.net/hwtgeo36/7/

You insert a number, and it returns a Star Wars character from a server (ex. 1 = Luke Skywalker). You can use the same logic with your own server.

Also, you would render your table here, instead of my example that replaces some html.

If you have troubles with this, please write back.

Comment: I think my problem is that I dove head first into this Project and immediately started following tutorials and things wthout really studying them properly, like I have NO idea what some of the things you said mean. I have a lot of studying and research to do.

But, thank you for the suggestion, I'm taking notes from all the answers I'm getting :)

Comment: @worseIntern Trust me, it's easy. I've been where you are. I'm a self taught developer with a business degree. If I could've learnt it, so can you. You can google the things I mentioned, or you can ask me what is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for these words, I'm really enjoying this project, especially the web design aspects, I'm slowly making my way to it ^^